# Change IP address from 192.x.y.z to 10.u.v.w for whole network with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Out Network moves from 192.x.y.z to 10.u.v.w and I don't want to readdress 250 Computers by hand. My idea is to use a powershell script (test for a single pc):

```
$oldIp='192.168.100.1'
$newIp='10.11.12.13'
$newGw='10.11.12.254'
$newLen='24'

$adminCred = Get-Credential -UserName ourdomain\myAdminAccount -Message 'Enter Password'

ForEach ($Adapter in (Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetEnabled='True'"  -ComputerName $oldIp )){
    
    $wmiQuery = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Index = '$($Adapter.Index)'" -ComputerName $oldIp
      
    if( $wmiQuery.IPAddress -contains $oldIp ){        

        $pcName=[system.net.dns]::gethostentry($lavIp) |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostName

        $cimSess=New-CimSession -SkipTestConnection -Credential $adminCred -ComputerName $pcName

        New-NetIPAddress -CimSession $cimSess  -InterfaceIndex $Adapter.Index -IPAddress $newIp -PrefixLength $newLen -DefaultGateway $newGw
        
    }else{
        ## do not touch this nic
    }
}
```

If all NICs got it's new IP, remove the old IP with `Remove-NetIPAddress`.

Currently, the `$cimSess` does not work as expected, but my main question is: Am I on the right track, or is there a better/faster/easier/... way to do this? Or am I completely wrong and missed something?

Comment: DHCP is a thing.

Answer (score 6):

You should use DHCP to provision the IP addresses for your network. All computers then have DHCP enabled, and they get the correct IP address from the DHCP server.

Comment: This is the *answer*. Use DHCP. If you for some reason think you require static addresses, use DHCP reservations.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. But it is not my decision and DHCP is currently not an option. We are forced to do this by higher authorities.